# User logged in on www, but not on non-www

Tags: nginx, dns

I have a problem where if the user logs into the site from www.domain.com, and then goes to domain.com (without the www), they don't appear as logged in. And if they go back to www.domain.com, they're logged in.

Why would this be happening?

I recently set up SSL on my server by following this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

I also changed my domain's DNS values to point to my server. I have an A-record for both domain.com and www.domain, which point to my server's elastic IP.

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
# Cache expires
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    expires $expires;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    expires $expires;

    include snippets/ssl-domain.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)\$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with your session, did you try to set the domain for your sessioncookie to www and non www?